# Generate a PDF logbook from git commits

Tags: git, github, pdf-generation

I know that I am able to view previous commits in various ways using git log but I was wondering if anybody here could recommend some good tools for creating a PDF or HTML logbook from git commits. I was hoping I would be able to generate something similar to the style of Github commit logs but with different info.

If people don't have any ideas on programs to generate these logs, what are their thoughts or recommendations if I attempt to make my own generator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the project is due quite soon i just wrote up a quick script myself to output a log the way i want to, it just scrapes the data from git-log and outputs it into a template (borrowed from github).

[Example output](http://www.importsoul.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/gitBook.html)

[More info](http://www.importsoul.net/python/pygitbook/)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using 'ccze' and -h (html output) switch

```
git log | ccze -A -h > gitlog.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one that generates a changelog from my tags.  You can read more about it [in my blog post](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/changelog.html), but the basic idea is that a well written tag should basically do it anyway and easily provide user-level docs.

Comment: That looks really nice but this is intended as part of a report to show that sustained effort has been put into the project

Comment: We do that with our code review system.  I built a [simple GUI](http://dustinphoto.iriscouch.com/gerrit/_design/app/index.html) on top of that to show what we're working on (in realtime).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Github anyway, I am wondering, why not save the html and the referred css files and run them through the html2pdf converter, say like [Pisa converter](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/).

With a little tweaking of the css I presume, you get high quality well formatted pdfs exactly like how you want them.

Alternatively, you can store the diffs in txt files and pass them through the libraries that include html to do syntax highlighting like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) and follow a similar process with Pisa, as above.

Comment: The git-hub logs are formatted in a way that i like but i would like to be able to add more relevant information such as additions and deletions. I think i might just borrow their HTML and make up quick python script to parse it using some kind of template engine.

Answer (score 0):

When working with GitLab, you can another method:
View the file in gitlab and select `view history`.
Print, save to pdf.