# Download git commit log from bitbucket within a date range

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-log

I want to download latest git commit log from the bitbucket as pdf/excel/any document type. I want to get commit log within a date range. So far, i have found some solution by using **git log .....**. I want a different option to get the log. How can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a PDF logbook from git commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489088/generate-a-pdf-logbook-from-git-commits)

Comment: You say `I want a different option to get the log`: could you explain the problem with using `git log`? What have you tried and how is it not working?